# Sharepoint 2013 Device Channel Mobile device access with different master page not working

Tags: sharepoint

I have created device channels, so that i can access my sp2013 website with a different master-page while accessing with mobile device. But still when i access the site, from different mobiles i get the same master page applied that is also the default master page.

I have done the following :

> 1. Created device channels(created 2 device channels)

[image: For All Mobiles]

[image: For IPAD-3]

> Now i applied the different master page for mobile devices

[image]

I have tried to access my site via :

1. Sony Xperia Arc S (Android 4.1)
2. IPad 3
3. Iphone IOS 4.0

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure the "Automatic Mobile Browser Redirection" feature was deactivated in site settings on the site you are trying to access?

edit: After testing I found that this feature only works for Site Master Pages.  If your page isn't a publishing page then it will take on the Master Page set for the System Master page.  Unfortunatley the only device channel available there is "All Channels"

Comment: Hi, I checked.. the feature is not activated. also the page is a publishing page.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "iPad" as device inclusion rule. instead of full device name. It worked for me. 
for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj862343.aspx